# I need to execute a python script via NSTask from a macOS app, but the script cannot find modules if the app is sandboxed. Any suggestion?

Tags: python, objective-c, macos, cocoa, appstore-sandbox

I would like to execute a python script via NSTask from a macOS application. My code is the following:

```
NSString *image1Path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"a1" ofType:@"jpg"];

NSString *image2Path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"a2" ofType:@"jpg"];

NSString *predictorPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks" ofType:@"dat"];

NSString *pythonScriptPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"faceMorph" ofType:@"py"];

NSTask *task = [NSTask new];
   
[task setExecutableURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/usr/bin/python"]];
   
[task setArguments:@[pythonScriptPath,@"-p1",image1Path,@"-p2",image2Path,@"-a",@"0.5",@"-ex",@"/Users/fofo/a3.jpg",@"-predictorpath",predictorPath]];
    

[task launch];
[task waitUntilExit];
```

If I disable sandboxing, the script runs just fine. However, if I enable sandboxing, the output is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/fofo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FaceMorph_macOS-cmfgvhivheuzioacarvvcyjpokyp/Build/Products/Debug/FaceMorph macOS.app/Contents/Resources/faceMorph.py", line 4, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: No module named cv2
```

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Where is the `cv2` module located? Is it bundled with your app? Also you should read Catalina [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-catalina-10_15-release-notes?preferredLanguage=occ): Scripting language runtimes such as Python, Ruby, and Perl are included in macOS for compatibility with legacy software. Future versions of macOS won’t include scripting language runtimes by default, and might require you to install additional packages. If your software depends on scripting languages, it’s recommended that you bundle the runtime within the app. ...

Comment: ... Use of Python 2.7 isn’t recommended as this version is included in macOS for compatibility with legacy software. Future versions of macOS won’t include Python 2.7. Instead, it’s recommended that you run python3 from within Terminal.